# DNN Ribbon not hiding for Non Registered Users

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have developed an application using DotNetNuke 7.0. The problem is that those users which are not assigned Admin privileges and are not assigned Edit Privileges, DNN Ribbon is still visible on the child pages for those users.
1. DNN Ribbon is not visible, which is ok
[image: DNN Ribbon is not visible, which is ok]

2. DNN Ribbon visible on child page, not correct!
[image: DNN Ribbon visible on child page, not correct]

3. Rights for registered users on home page
[image: Rights for registered users on home page]

4. Rights for registered users on child page
[image: Rights for registered users on child page]

5. Rights for that specific user
[image: User rights]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. There are three possible options for that rights. One is tick icon which means giving  access to the right, second is deny icon, which deny the rights (I didn't select the option).. I was rather selecting the 3rd option with no icon (as you can see on the image in the question) which giving the Edit right to the user. Long story short, Selecting the 'deny' icon (instead of no icon) restricts the user from Edit rights.
[image: Selecting Deny Icon instead of No icon]

Comment: That is not completely correct. Checked means: Permission granted. Deny means: Permission denied. Unchecked means: Permission can be granted somewhere else (e.g. if the user is member of a group that has the permission, or for the module permissions it can be granted in the page permissions), if this is not the case it is denied. But there were some issues with this in DNN 7 as far as I remember...

Answer (score 2):

Please check if there is a module on the page where non-registered users have edit permissions. Most of the times this is the reason for that.

Best wishes
Michael

Comment: sorry Michael, that isn't the case. I've checked all modules, and none of them have the Edit Permissions for Non-Registered users.